# Sed with special characters in the string and using a variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I'm try to use `sed` (with `-i` option) to replace password in a config file by a bash script.

My config file is:

```
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']                             = '0';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = '';
```

I need to update these values passing variables with special characters (`. - /` etc...)

I need to have this result:

```
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'mydb.lab.local';
$DB['PORT']                             = '3306';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = 'Passw0rd!';
```

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['PORT'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['PORT'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['SERVER'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['SERVER'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['PASSWORD'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['PASSWORD'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i "/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a \$DB['PORT']='3306';" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i '/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a $DB['SERVER']='"${db_instance_address}"';' /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i '/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a $DB['PASSWORD']='"${db_password}"';' /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
```

the output is:

```
egrep "SERVER|PORT|PASSWORD" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php

$DB['PASSWORD']='';
$DB['PORT']='3306';
$DB['SERVER'] = '';
//$DB['SERVER']                   = 'localhost';
//$DB['PORT']                            = '0';
//$DB['PASSWORD']                        = '';
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please list all supported chars for the password. what's the syntax spec of the conf file? what if the password include `'` chars?

Comment: please update the question with a sample password containing all of your 'special characters'; please update the question with details on what you mean by *`doesn't work`* ... error? wrong result? no changes? something else?

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting the output you show. The quotes in `$DB['PASSWORD']` will not be written to the file, because they match the quote delimiters around the string.

Comment: the latest update (to the question) shows two sets of `SERVER/PORT/PASSWORD` in the *php file; are you looking to change both `PASSWORD` entries or just one (and if so, *which* one)?

Comment: it's only one. I comment the existing and try to add a new value, but I have problem with the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the support.

I solved with this code:

```
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['PORT'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['PORT'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php 
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['SERVER'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['SERVER'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php 
sudo sed -i "s/\$DB\\['PASSWORD'\\]/\\/\\/\$DB\\['PASSWORD'\\]/g" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php 
sudo sed -i "/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a \$DB['PORT'] = '3306';" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php 
sudo sed -i '/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a \$DB[\'\''SERVER\'\''] = \'\'''"${db_instance_address}"'\'\'';' /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
sudo sed -i '/^.*Zabbix GUI configuration file.*/a \$DB[\'\''PASSWORD\'\''] = \'\'''"${db_password}"'\'\'';' /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
```

The output is:

```
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'Passw0rd!';
$DB['SERVER'] = 'mydb.lab.local';
$DB['PORT'] = '3306';
//$DB['SERVER']                 = 'localhost';
//$DB['PORT']                           = '0';
//$DB['PASSWORD']                       = '';
```

The best solution is to replace existing row, but I can't do it, and I comment and create a new row.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `gnu-awk` instead `sed` since a password string can contain any character that might create issues in a `sed`'s replacement string:

```bash
awk -i inplace -v ins="$db_instance_address" -v pw="$db_password" -v port="$db_port" '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="="}
index($1, "$DB[\047SERVER") {
   $2 = " \047" ins "\047;"
}
index($1, "$DB[\047PASSWORD") {
   $2 = " \047" pw "\047;"
}
index($1, "$DB[\047PORT") {
   $2 = " \047" port "\047;"
} 1' file

$DB['SERVER']                   = 'mydb.lab.local';
$DB['PORT']                             = '3306';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = 'Passw0rd!';
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't work

Comment: There are 3 problems: 1. don't save the new values, 2. replace for all servers (not only for the ```DB['SERVER']```, 3. add ```'``` to all others variables.

Comment: ok all the issues are there because only I assumed the input file is exactly as shown in question i.e. those 3 lines. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "/^$DB/{
    /SERVER/s/'[^']*/'${db_server}/3
    /PORT/s/'[^']*/'${db_port}/3
    /PASSWORD/s/'[^']*/'${db_password}/3
}" /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'mydb.lab.local';
$DB['PORT']                             = '3306';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = 'Passw0rd!';
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tested but it didn't change the values.